# How to Call Stored Procedures from SQL using MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, mybatis, ibatis

I've got a working program in Java which is using SQLServer as DB. I know how to use the 'normal' way of using MyBatis like:

```
<select id="getAllWeapons" resultType="String" parameterType="Map">
        select distinct weaponId 
        from WeaponTab;
</select>
```

However Im curious if Im able to call Stored Procedures existing in the SQL database that others wrote to make my life easier.

Any documentation or tips to the right direction will do.

I did some digging and saw this:

```
<select id = "callById" resultMap = "result" parameterType = "Student" statementType = "CALLABLE">
      {call read_record_byid(#{id, jdbcType = INTEGER, mode = IN})}
</select>
```

So does it mean the keyword to using Stored Procedures is **call**?

Comment: Here are executable demos : [a simple one](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-58230726) and [a complex one](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/blob/master/so-56633915).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is definition as specification of JDBC(`CallableStatement`). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html.